# ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I know there's a lot of of question about this error, in most of answers the solution is equal properties or primary key error, what is not the case but i still can't get what's wrong with this;

```
Carteira.ID INT(11) PK
Acionista.Carteira INT(11) PK
```

**The Acionistas Table**
[image]

**The Carteira Table**
[image]

```
 ALTER TABLE `acoes_db`.`Carteira` 
 ADD CONSTRAINT `carteira_fk`
   FOREIGN KEY (`ID`)
   REFERENCES `acoes_db`.`Acionistas` (`Carteira`)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

[image]

**The Error**
[image]

Comment: A foreign key references a primary key. The PK in Acionistas is `CPF, Carteira`, not just `Carteira`. You have to reference the *entire* primary key.

Comment: @HoneyBadger but `CPF` do not has the same type, and from what i'm seeing in workbench i can set only one column in "referenced column"

Comment: You would need to have `CPF` in `Carteira` as well. I don't know workbench, so can't help you there.

Comment: @HoneyBadger but `CPF` its `VARCHAR(15)` the fk `INT(11)`. Curious is that the inverse works, but to delete some `Acionista` i need to delete `Carteira` first, what it's not logic, why it's `CASCADE on DELETE`

Comment: A foreign key doesn't have a datatype, you should view it more as a bridge between attributes. You should add `CPF` to the `Carteira` table. Then you can add the FK: `ADD CONSTRAINT carteira_fk
   FOREIGN KEY (ID, CPF)
   REFERENCES acoes_db.Acionistas (Carteira, CPF)`